# How to get Facebook comment plugin in blog?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, errors, facebook

I am trying to use Facebook social plugin to my blog. I tried few Wordpress plugins but getting error in it.

Lastly, I tried using Flexo Facebook Manager(http://www.flexostudio.com/flexo-facebook-manager.html). But the problem still persists. The Facebook commenting tool is not coming in my blog. When clicked to Open graph it shows this error.

Errors That Must Be Fixed

Object Invalid Value:   Object at URL 'http://buggingweb.com/2012/01/operating-system-in-your-browser-linux/' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value 'User ID' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

Missing Required Property:  The og:url property is required, but not present.

Missing Required Property:  The og:type property is required, but not present.

Missing Required Property:  The og:title property is required, but not present.

Am not able to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your page:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="test"/><br>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="YOUR_NAME_WHAT_YOU_WANT"/><br>
<meta property="og:url" content="YOUR_URL"/><br>
```